# Are lawmakers forbidden from bringing their children to the chamber?

Tags: united-states, congress

There was a [recent story in Japan](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2017/11/29/national/social-issues/kumamoto-assembly-woman-slapped-with-official-warning-bringing-baby-to-work/) where a parent brought her child to work, but according to the council rules, no-one other than the lawmakers are allowed into the chamber when in session.

In the US national congress, do such rules exist, and have lawmakers taken their children with them into the chambers? The situation in individual states or in other countries would also be interesting to hear, but for the sake of narrowing down the question, how would this be handled at a US national level?

Comment: Australian case: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirstie_Marshall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for the Senate are the "Standing Rules", and in particular [Rule XXIII — Privilege of the Floor](https://www.rules.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=RuleXXIII). The House has similar rules

There is a list of those permitted on the floor of the Senate while it is in session. The list includes the President, Supreme court judges, Officials on their duty, the leaders of the Army and Navy, the Chaplain and the Secretary of the Smithsonian Institute.

Children are not allowed in the Senate while it is in session. As far as I am aware, the situation of breastfeeding in the chamber has never arisen, indeed cnn notes that ["it's hard to imagine a woman nursing on the House floor"](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/05/10/opinions/australian-breastfeeding-senator-filipovic/index.html). It seems likely that an older child would not be permitted on the floor of the Senate, though they could view from the gallery.